# Source for translating סופר as scribe in Kiddushin

Tags: translation, mishna, english

The Sefaria's translation of the Mishnah in [Kiddushin 4, 13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Kiddushin.4.13?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&p2=Jastrow%2C_%D7%A1%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A4%D6%B5%D7%A8&lang2=bi) says:

> לֹא יִלְמַד אָדָם רַוָּק סוֹפְרִים, וְלֹא תִלְמַד אִשָּׁה סוֹפְרִים.
>
> An unmarried man must not learn to be a scribe, nor may a woman learn to be a scribe.

Every other translation and explanation I saw everywhere incl Schottenstein is "school teacher, primary teacher" because it fits the idea of the prohibition.

What is the source of translating it as "scribe", as women are not Kosher for writing scrolls and there's no problem of Yihud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to come from [this translation](http://learn.conservativeyeshiva.org/kiddushin-chapter-four-mishnah-thirteen/) on the website of the Conservative Yeshivah in Jerusalem, authored by [Dr Joshua Kulp](http://learn.conservativeyeshiva.org/author/joshkulp/).

Note that in his comments to the *mishnah* he writes:

> Part of a scribes work was to teach children how to read and perhaps how to write.  In those days, it was often the child's mother who would bring the child to school.  Hence the teacher would have a lot of contact with the children's mothers.  Therefore, a man who has never been married should not learn to be a scribe/teacher, lest he come into too much contact with the mothers.  Furthermore, sometimes men would bring their children to school.  Hence, women and even married women should not be teachers.

Thus, he essentially agrees with the other commentaries you note that the *mishnah* is discussing a teacher of children.

Comment: THank you, but seriously, can Sefaria's translation come from a conservative site? I don't see a need to bend it that far as Rashi in place says "a teacher".

Comment: I don't think Sefaria are looking at all to push an exclusively Orthodox point of view. From their [FAQ](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Project/wiki/General-FAQ): "We want to offer access to as many points of view as possible, but we don’t want to impose points of view on anyone."

Comment: But the Mishna? Are there other translations on this site?

Comment: Looks like they have three other translations (on at least some mishnayot): Wikisource, their own Sefaria Community translation, and R. Shraga Silverstein

Comment: How do I get them, please? and what do they say?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kiddushin?lang=bi Then click on 'versions' towards the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you so they chose the first one arbitrarily?

Comment: I've no idea how they choose the default translation